# Positioning a path.lineTo()

Tags: java, android, canvas

I'm currently learning Canvas on Android Studio and I'm not so sure about using the right title, but I'm stuck on how to control the triangle position when dragging the Red dot using Seekbar. below are the details

Below are the codes that I've successfully drawn a triangle.

```
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(100, 300, 900, 700, 50, 50,paint);

        Point pointTop = new Point(250, 400);
        Point pointLeft = new Point(150, 150);
        Point pointRight = new Point(350, 150);


        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.lineTo(pointTop.x, pointTop.y);
        path.lineTo(pointLeft.x, pointLeft.y);
        path.lineTo(pointRight.x, pointRight.y);
        path.lineTo(pointTop.x, pointTop.y);
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
```

Image result:

[image]

Expected result

Note: there are only 1 Red dot and 1 triangle.

[image]

much appreciated =)

Answer (score 1):

I've solved my problem after reading through the documents as below link and added the codes

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path

Enjoy :)

```
        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        paint.setColor(Color.RED);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(100, 300, 900, 700, 50, 50,paint);

        Point pointTop = new Point(250, 400);
        Point pointLeft = new Point(150, 150);
        Point pointRight = new Point(350, 150);


        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
--------------------- added -------------------------------
        path.moveTo(pointLeft.x, pointLeft.y);
        path.moveTo(pointRight.x, pointRight.y);
        path.moveTo(pointTop.x, pointTop.y);
        path.reset();
--------------------- added -------------------------------
        path.setFillType(Path.FillType.EVEN_ODD);
        path.lineTo(pointTop.x, pointTop.y);
        path.lineTo(pointLeft.x, pointLeft.y);
        path.lineTo(pointRight.x, pointRight.y);
        path.lineTo(pointTop.x, pointTop.y);
        path.close();

        canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html) class and then especially [setTranslateX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#setTranslateX-double-).

Comment: Hi DrPhill, thanks for the advise. After few hours of reading, I admit that my basics are not good enough, therefore sorry I still have no idea how to use it to apply on my problem :(